Delphi FMX TPathData overlapping vectors
I want to use TPathData to create grid-like forms to then print to a canvas using DrawPath, but I do not want to print directly to the canvas using DrawRect and the like. Here is a simplified example of my problem using two superimposed rectangles to form a plus sign. The problem is this: when rendered on the canvas, the middle of the cross is white:

Here is the method I used to create this image:
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PD: TPathData;
    aRect1, aRect2: TRectF;
begin

 aRect1 := RectF(45,10,55,90);
 aRect2 := RectF(10,45,90,55);

  PD := TPathData.Create;

    begin
      PD.MoveTo(aRect1.TopLeft);
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Top));
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Bottom));
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Left,aRect1.Bottom));
      PD.LineTo(aRect1.TopLeft);
    end;

    begin
      PD.MoveTo(aRect2.TopLeft);
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Top));
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Bottom));
      PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Left,aRect2.Bottom));
      PD.LineTo(aRect2.TopLeft);
    end;

    ImageControl1.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Width), Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Height));
    if ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
    try
      with ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas do
      begin
        clear(0);
        Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
        Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
        Stroke.Thickness := 1;
        DrawPath(PD,1);
        FillPath(PD,1);
      end;
    finally
      ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
      FreeAndNil(PD);
    end;

end;

I want the whole image, including the middle bit, to filled in. Does anyone know how to do this (keeping in mind that my real-life situations are more complex than this simple cross, but they are composed in any case of superimposed rectangles of various dimensions). I want to be able to create the image in a TPathData object ready to be printed without further adjustments.
Thanks in advance.

Is there are reason you're not creating a separate TPathData for each path?  If each path has its own TPathData, you don't get this problem.

@PhilipJ.Rayment Perhaps you could post it as an answer?

I know it works if I draw each beam of the grid separately on the canvas, but I am only able to pass a single TPathData object, which has to contain the entire grid, to the canvas (I won't go into the why of this). So I was wondering if it is indeed possible in Firemonkey to create a grid with TPathData without creating white squares where the beams overlap.

Give each path its own TPathData.
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PD1, PD2: TPathData;
    aRect1, aRect2: TRectF;
begin

 aRect1 := RectF(45,10,55,90);
 aRect2 := RectF(10,45,90,55);

  PD1 := TPathData.Create;
  PD2 := TPathData.Create;

  PD1.MoveTo(aRect1.TopLeft);
  PD1.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Top));
  PD1.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Bottom));
  PD1.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Left,aRect1.Bottom));
  PD1.LineTo(aRect1.TopLeft);

  PD2.MoveTo(aRect2.TopLeft);
  PD2.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Top));
  PD2.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Bottom));
  PD2.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Left,aRect2.Bottom));
  PD2.LineTo(aRect2.TopLeft);

  ImageControl1.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Width), Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Height));
  if ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    with ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas do
    begin
      clear(0);
      Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
      Stroke.Thickness := 1;
      DrawPath(PD1,1);
      FillPath(PD1,1);
      DrawPath(PD2,1);
      FillPath(PD2,1);
    end;
  finally
    ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    PD1.Free;
    PD2.Free;
  end;
end;

EDIT
Given that you want to create a grid, this is probably a better way to go, and only uses a single TPathData.  It uses a for loop, and offsets the TRectF variables on each iteration.
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PD: TPathData;
    aRect1, aRect2: TRectF;
    i:  Integer;
    NumLoops:   integer;
begin

  aRect1 := RectF(45,10,55,170);
  aRect2 := RectF(10,45,170,55);
  NumLoops:=2;

  ImageControl1.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Width), Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Height));
  if ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    with ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas do
    begin
      clear(0);
      Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
      Stroke.Thickness := 2;

      for i:=1 to NumLoops do begin
        PD := TPathData.Create;
        PD.MoveTo(aRect1.TopLeft);
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Top));
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Right,aRect1.Bottom));
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect1.Left,aRect1.Bottom));
        PD.ClosePath;
        aRect1.Offset(80,0);

        DrawPath(PD,1);
        FillPath(PD,1);
        PD.Free;

        PD:=TPathData.Create;
        PD.MoveTo(aRect2.TopLeft);
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Top));
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Right,aRect2.Bottom));
        PD.LineTo(PointF(aRect2.Left,aRect2.Bottom));
        PD.ClosePath;
        aRect2.Offset(0,80);

        DrawPath(PD,1);
        FillPath(PD,1);
        PD.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

end;


Thanks for your answer. Of course I know that the approach you outline works, but I think I was not entirely clear: I want a single TPathData object to contain the entire grid, not just single beams. I have not been able to do this successfully without having the problem I illustrate above.

Okay, how do you feel about painting whites squares on a black background?
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PD: TPathData;
    r,c:    Integer;
begin
  ImageControl1.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Width), Round(ImageControl1.BoundsRect.Height));
  if ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    with ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas do
    begin
      Clear(TAlphaColorRec.Black);
      Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
      Stroke.Thickness := 2;

      PD := TPathData.Create;
      for r := 0 to 3 do begin
        for c := 0 to 3 do begin
          PD.MoveTo(PointF(c * 90 + 10, r * 90 + 10));
          PD.HLineToRel(80);
          PD.VLineToRel(80);
          PD.HLineToRel(-80);
          PD.ClosePath;
        end;
      end;

      DrawPath(PD,1);
      FillPath(PD,1);
      PD.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ImageControl1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;


Thank you again, @philip-j-rayment. I really appreciate your input. Yes, it looks like the only work around is to create lots of rectangles in the TPathData, so in my example instead of two intersecting rectangles, I would need five (the four outside bits and the middle)! I guess I can do that, I was just hoping for a simpler solution!
